# One for all or individual Pivot for every many to many in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, relational-database

i dont know that i'm doing right or wrong..
i want to make a blog that have multiple categories and tags with many to many relation.

should i make a pivot table for each one like:

```
       "category_post"
        $table->integer('post_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
```

and another one for Tags table...
or can i make one table for both with an extra column that can filter throw that?

```
       "pivot_post"
        $table->integer('post_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->integer('pivot_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->string('type');
```

but.. if i can make one for all, i dont know hot make db and relation??
and which one is better for performance..?
1 big relation tableor multiple relation table?
tnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for a polymorphic relationship if you wanna accomplish this with a single table.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations

Comment: even if you made it worked via polymorphic relationship I recommend to create a separate pivot table with many to many relationship.as polymorphic relationships has known bugs in whereHas queries.

Comment: i found that what i need is Many To Many Polymorphic Relations but thanks for the advice of not using..    ;-).. i will go with the seprate pivot for each one..